# phone_mobile validation prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop

I am trying to do another validation in the prestashop in phone_mobile field at checkout. The validation i am trying to do is to detect the first 2 numbers that user types in this field. So, if it's not the specific numbers (04) then if he trying to continue i want to show an error when click continue order. How can i do that? Where the **isPhoneNumber function** take place? Where can i edit it?

Can i do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#phone_mobile').change(function(){

        if($(this).val()!='04'){
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('form-ok').addClass('form-error');
        }

        });
});
```

I think that will work as an error but in the end if the user click to continue , he will do it normally with no errors at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Witch version of Prestashop are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#phone_mobile').on("input", function(){
        if($(this).val().substring(0,1)!='04') {
           $(this).closest('div').removeClass('form-ok').addClass('form-error');
        }
    });
});
```

you can use substring to get your requirement done..
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp here is the tutorial.

Comment: As a jquery validation works but the user in the end can continue his order with no errors even if this input has the class form-error..

Comment: Hi.. You need to validate it.. Check for the count of classes .form-error.. And if the count returns greater than 0 then return false.